# Ao instalar o visual studio 2017 no meu windows 7 ocorre o erro. Visual studio 2015 é instalado normalmente

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Ao instalar o visual studio 2017 no meu windows 7 ocorre o erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2018-03-19T13:04:58 : Verbose : Visual Studio Installer (1.15.3242.223 : release) ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installershell.exe","/finalizeInstall","install","--in","C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_201803191304047741.json","--locale","pt-BR","--activityId","3299ceb4-e71f-4825-b27d-1bf113cddaa7","--campaign","764900370.1519227822"]
2018-03-19T13:05:22 : Verbose : Creating VS Telemetry Survey
2018-03-19T13:05:28 : Verbose : Starting ServiceHub Remote Settings client.
2018-03-19T13:05:28 : Verbose : Received the application ready notification
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : ProgressBarService listening to ipc channel: progress-bar
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: LoggerService
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: LoggerService
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : FeaturesIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : FeaturesIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : Telemetry Session ID: ef69c0dc-67bc-43c7-bb9c-d98e2d602072
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : Creating Start menu shortcut [shortcutName: Visual Studio Installer, targetPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe]
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : Starting the setup updater service.
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : Service creation finished
2018-03-19T13:05:29 : Verbose : Installation finalized successfully.
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Attempted connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient': location is null
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Attempted connection to service 'SetupUpdater': location is null
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Remote Settings Ipc Service creation failed.
error: [TypeError] Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Failed to start the setup updater service. error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Verbose : Window showing
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Failed to create VS Telemetry Survey [error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3]
2018-03-19T13:05:32 : Error : Create shortcut failed: Path must be a string. Received undefined
2018-03-19T13:05:39 : Verbose : FeedbackIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeedbackProxy
2018-03-19T13:05:47 : Verbose : Window ready
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Getting installed product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Starting the installed products provider service.
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Starting the products provider service.
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Attempted connection to service 'ProductsProvider': location is null
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to start the products provider service. error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to start the installed products provider service. error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to get installed product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine, error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3]
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Getting product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Starting the products provider service.
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Attempted connection to service 'ProductsProvider': location is null
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to start the products provider service. error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to get product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine, error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
    at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:76:21)
    at HubClient.requestService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubClient.js:63:21)
    at Object.startRemoteSettingsClient (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\remote-settings\service-hub\remote-settings-client.js:236:22)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\main\rpc-factory.js:40:41
    at 
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3]
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Verbose : Starting the installer service.
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Attempted connection to service 'Installer': location is null
2018-03-19T13:05:48 : Error : Failed to start the installer service. error: Path must be a string. Received undefined at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)
    at getUserSpecificSalt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From previous event:
    at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19)
    at Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20)
    at ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
    at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
    at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)